# Finding nth element in a list using Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that retrieves the nth element in a list.

Here's what I have so far:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do print (nth 3 [1,2,10])

nth _ [] = [] 
nth a (x:xs) 
 | (a == 1) = x 
 | otherwise = nth (a-1) xs
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error occurred
ERROR line 2 - Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : main
*** Type          : IO ()
*** Given context : ()
*** Constraints   : (Show a, Num [a])
```

Comment: Try writing a type annotation for `nth` (this is a good practice anyway). That should make the problem here more apparent.

Comment: Why don't you just use xs !! n ?

Comment: Since you want `nth` to return an *element* of the list, you surely want it to have type `Int -> [a] -> a`, right? Well, your first definition, `nth _ [] = []`, is a *list* (or "returns a list", if you prefer), so it's a definition of a function of type `Int -> [a] -> [a]`. So what *should* `nth` do with an empty list? That's a good question! One way is to simply have it fail, another is to give it return type `Maybe a`, with `Nothing` returned in case the list is too short.

Comment: But what doe sthe error message say? Any ideas?

Comment: The error message is not helpful here. That happens quite often in Haskell, _when you fail to give enough type annotations_. Since you haven't told it what the type of `nth` is supposed to be, the compiler figures out some amazing (and often rather ridiculous) signature and only notices a the call site (here, `main`) that it's bogus. That's why you get an error message demandig `Num [a]`, which is obviously weird and one of the typical signs that you've made an error somewhere else and didn't build a safety-net in form of an explicit type signature there.

Comment: Ok guys, I solved it. Basically, my base case was wrong. I simply want to retrieve an element at a specific positon. so there is no need ot worry about an empty list in this situation. My base case should be (a==1) = x. Everything else is the same.

Comment: @leftaroundabout actually for some reason, here it was informative enough. :) It says that it wants to read `1` as type `[a]` which is also an instance of `Num` (to be compared by `==1`). And `Show [a]` entails `Show a`, so that's the second constraint.

Answer (score 5):

Why `Num [a]` constraint? Because in the `[]` clause you have your function returning a list, `[]`, and in the other clause you have it return a list's element, `x`. Which means that it is only defined for lists whose elements are lists themselves. But you call it with a list of `[1,2,10]`. So Haskell sees a numeric literal `1` and wants to interpret it as a list that is also a number. It also needs it to be an instance of `Show` for `print` to be able to show it:

```
Prelude> :i print
print :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()         -- Defined in System.IO
```

Comment: This is why it's helpful to write explicit function signatures, so you can see that you're obviously trying to return a different type than what you've declared.

Comment: @alxp it is also oftentimes helpful to not write any type signature at all, especially for a newbie, BUT - after loading the definition, to inspect the *inferred* signature: `Prelude> let {nth _ [] = [];nth a (x:xs) = x} --
Prelude> :i nth -- 
nth :: t -> [[a]] -> [a]`.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning list in clause

```
nth _ [] = []
```

and a list element in clause

```
nth a (x:xs) 
  | (a == 1) = x 
  | otherwise = nth (a-1) xs
```

so the type of your function is

```
*Main> :t nth
nth :: (Eq a1, Num a1) => a1 -> [[a]] -> [a]
```

you can check this out. Your function can not return element of any index for any list, so you must use Maybe to return "element not found"

```
nth _ [] = Nothing
nth a (x:xs) 
 | (a == 1) = Just x 
 | otherwise = nth (a-1) xs


*Main> :t nth
nth :: (Eq a1, Num a1) => a1 -> [a] -> Maybe a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
nth a (x:xs) 
| (a == 1) = x 
| otherwise = nth (a-1) xs
```